# Hibernate 6.x fails Could not resolve org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final

Tags: hibernate, gradle, hibernate-6.x

I am trying to run hibernate 6.1.6 project. It fails as it seems not to be able to find org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final somewhere internally

I tried adding it to local folder and adding to flatDir gradle
tried adding to IDEA dependencies as jar file as additional lib
tried putting explicit dependency in gradle - it fails trying to get that
tried adding as many maven repositories as I could - no effect

Any suggestions? Does hibernate 6.x works at all is it  broken for everybody?
5.6.x works perfectly well though

### Stacktrace:

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':MysqlSessionFactory.main()'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':runtimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final.
     Required by:
         project : > org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.6.Final > org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.1.6.Final
      > No matching variant of org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
```

### build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "net.serenity-bdd.serenity-gradle-plugin" version "3.4.2"
    id 'java'
//    id "org.hibernate.orm" version "5.6.0.Final"
}

defaultTasks 'clean', 'test', 'aggregate'

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs './libs'
    }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repo.clojars.org"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://clojars.org/repo/"
    }

//    maven (uri("/Users/802619/projects/silverbird/testautomation/silverbird-serenity-autotest/libs/hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.2.Final.jar"))

}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    slf4jVersion = '1.7.7'
    serenityCoreVersion = '3.4.2'
    junitVersion = '5.8.2'
    assertJVersion = '3.23.1'
    lombokVersion = '1.18.24'
    logbackVersion = '1.2.11'
    redisVersion = '4.3.1'
    mysqlVersion = '8.0.32'
    hibernateVersion = '6.1.6'
    glassfishVersion = '3.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    'org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:6.0.2.Final'
    testImplementation "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-core:${serenityCoreVersion}",
            "net.serenity-bdd:serenity-junit5:${serenityCoreVersion}",
            "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}",
            "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}",
            "org.assertj:assertj-core:${assertJVersion}",
            "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombokVersion}",
            "ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:${logbackVersion}"


    implementation "redis.clients:jedis:${redisVersion}"
    implementation "mysql:mysql-connector-java:${mysqlVersion}"
    implementation('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:6.1.6.Final')
//    implementation('org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.6.1.Final')
//    implementation "org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-gradle-plugin:5.2.16.Final"
    "org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:${glassfishVersion}"
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
}

gradle.startParameter.continueOnFailure = true

serenity {
    reports = ["single-page-html"]

    // // Specify the root package of any JUnit acceptance tests
    testRoot="frontoffice"
}

test.finalizedBy(aggregate)
//apply plugin: "org.hibernate.orm"
```

### Usage

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

import java.util.List;

public class MysqlSessionFactory {

    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        final StandardServiceRegistry registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure() // configures settings from hibernate.cfg.xml
                .build();
        try {
            return new MetadataSources(registry).buildMetadata().buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // The registry would be destroyed by the SessionFactory, but we had trouble building the SessionFactory
            // so destroy it manually.
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void closeFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory != null) {
            sessionFactory.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Display the string.
        NativeApiIllustrationTest test = new NativeApiIllustrationTest();
//        test.testBasicUsage();
    }
}
```

### Works with 5.6.x!

Comment: Looks like your local maven repository might be messed up. Try deleting the folder `~/.m2/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations` and re-run your build

Comment: I ran `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/` 
`rm -rf ~/.m2` with no effect

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. The dependency is on maven central (see https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations/6.0.6.Final/jar), so whatever is going on with your system/network, the problem is on your side.

Comment: I know I was able to download jar file for that. Even though gradle cannot find it. 5.x version doesn't have such problem

Comment: i think the problem is `sourceCompatibility = 1.8`. i don't think hibernate 6 supports java 8. it needs at least java 11.

Answer (score 0):

Try use org.hibernate.orm :

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:6.0.2.Final'
```